# jQuery proxy, context not as expected

Tags: jquery, proxy

I'm relatively new to writing jquery plugins and was hoping someone could explain why my code in the following simplified jsFiddle does not resolve as expected.  From reading the API and numerous tutorial blogs (most just rehashing the same examples) I am none the wiser why the proxy does not output "correct" instead of "wrong".

http://jsfiddle.net/Sheepish666/hZUvx/

```
!function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var plugin = function (element, options){
        this.init("plugin", element, options);
    };

    plugin.prototype = {
        constructor: plugin,

        string : "correct",

        init : function(type, element, options){
            this.type = type;
            this.$element = $(element);
            this.options = this.getOptions(options);
        },
        getOptions: function (options) {
            options = $.extend({}, $.fn[this.type].defaults, options, this.$element.data());
            return options;
        },

        test : function(){
            this.options.callbackFn("no proxy"); 
            $.proxy(this.options.callbackFn("proxy"), this);
        }
    };

    //

    var instance = null;
    $.fn.plugin = function( option, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 ){
        if(instance === null){
            var options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
            instance = new plugin(options);
        }
        if (typeof option == 'string') instance[option](arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
        return instance;
    };

    $.fn.plugin.Constructor = plugin;

    $.fn.plugin.defaults = {
        string : "wrong",
        callbackFn : function(type){
            $("body").html($("body").html() + type + " = "+ this.string + "<br>");
        }
    };

}(window.jQuery);

$.fn.plugin().test();
```

Thank you very much in advance :)